# How to use an array pass by parameter to some assembly func using C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, assembly

I have a problem trying to figure how access the values from an array. The important parts of the code look like this.

```
unsigned int A[]  = {1,1,1,3};

extern "C" bool isItValid(unsigned int A[]);
```

My question is, how do I work with the values from the array? Also, the real values of the array are 6 hex numbers of 32 bits each.

Comment: well, have you seen the syntax `A[0]`? If not, I would encourage you to read a tutorial on C/C++.

Comment: Are you *writing* the asm function? if so, writing a dummy C function taking an `unsigned int []` parameter and compiling with -S (generate assembly) would probably be pretty informative in seeing how the setup is done on the callee side. And know that the *calling convention* being used *will* play a role in this.

Comment: That depends on the ABI, that's actually used with your toolchain.